# 2 dimensional array of managed object c++

Tags: oop, multidimensional-array, c++-cli, managed

I am attempting to create a grid of hexagons on a windows form.

To do this i have created a 'hexagon' class with the header file as follows:

```
ref class Hexagon
{
public:
    Hexagon(int X, int Y, int I, int J);
    Hexagon();
private:
    array<Point>^ vertices;
    Point Centre;
    int i, j;
public:
    int GetX();
    int GetY();
    void SetCentre(int X, int Y);
    void CalculateVertices();
    array<Point>^ GetVertices();
    void drawHexagon();
};
```

i then want to have a 2 dimensional array storing these hexagons. my attempt at doing this is as follows:

`array<Hexagon^,2>^ Grid`

but i get the 'a variable with static storage duration cannot have a handle or tracking reference type'

how do i create a 2d array to add hexagons to?

Comment: This isn't C++ code. You need a different language tag.

Comment: is it not?! im doing it in a c++ file using a c++ compiler in visual studio 2012, im just using .NET DLL?

Comment: Definitely not. It is probably some kind of hybrid language supporting *some* part of C++ syntax. But this code is not valid C++.

Comment: just done a quick bit of research - the language is not called C++, it's called C++/CLI. One reason why it's called thus might be that plain C++ is a complete subset of C++/CLI (i.e. any conformant C++ program is also a conformant C++/CLI program).

Comment: @JabbaWook I would advise you to rely on "regular" c++ if you dont have any good reason to use this extension.

Comment: Indeed, if you want to use .NET, use C# or VB.Net. If you want to write native code, use C++. C++/CLI is meant for interoperability between .NET and native code. It has many drawbacks and not all Visual Studio or C++ features work in this mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *ref class* declares a class which is managed by the garbage collector.  One strong restriction that the C++/CLI compiler applies to such declarations is that such class cannot contain non-managed objects.  That very often turns out poorly when the object is moved when the heap is compacted, invalidating unmanaged pointers to such non-managed objects.

The likely trouble-maker is the `Point` type, there are no other candidates.  A sample declaration for a managed Point type that doesn't have this problem is:

```
   public value struct Point {
       int x, y;
   };
```

Or use the baked-in System::Drawing::Point type instead.